# Admin Panel and Main Page missing buttons/images

Tags: magento2, admin

I'm new to Magento and just installed the latest version on my localhost with xammp. I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Voq2XarSSBA
but at 6:20 I am not able to deploy the content like in the video. I receive an error.

[image]

Comment: Run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to your Magento Installation.
2. Open **app/etc/di.xml**.
3. Make Changes in **`<item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink</item>`**.
4. Replace **Symlink** with **Copy**.
5. Go to **pub/static** folder.
6. Delete everything except **.htaccess** file.