# After installation, I have problems with Magento 2

Tags: magento2, css, frontend-error

[image]

When I click on Products or another category the options are not displayed.

[image]

Does anyone has the solution of this problem?

Comment: Did you run static deploy command?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Admin Panel and Main Page missing buttons/images](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/152121/admin-panel-and-main-page-missing-buttons-images)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **The issue is occur because after install magento 2 you haven't deploy its static content. So magento 2 unable to find your css and js.
>   To resolve this issue run below commands in the root directory of your site:**

1. **php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer** (set the mode of
   environment is developer)
2. **php bin/magento setup:di:compile**(it will generate all the proxies
   and dependencies )
3. **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy** (it will deploy all the
   static content)
4. **php bin/magento cache:clean** and **php bin/magento cache:flush**(clear
   the cache)

It will resolve  the issue.

Also for more refernce check this link - [No images or JS on new Magento 2 installation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96289/no-images-or-js-on-new-magento-2-installation)

Comment: When I write the command, show me the next message:

Could not open input file: bin/magento

And the same with the others commands

Comment: But the link that you added worked me, thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

After install magento you have to run command deploy static content with your locale site.

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy [your locale site]

Hope it help you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your Magento Installation.
2. Open **app/etc/di.xml**.
3. Make Changes in **`<item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink</item>`**.
4. Replace **Symlink** with **Copy**.
5. Go to **pub/static** folder.
6. Delete everything except **.htaccess** file.