# Magento 2.2.4 : Missing media/styles.css from Sample Data site

Tags: magento2, css, luma-theme

Everything seems fine apart from the banner section which appears on various pages which looks like...

[image]

I can see that some styles are available in the install at `<install_dir>/pub/media/styles.css` but this file isn't included in the generated markup so it's not calling a 404.

Answer (score 5):

**Explaination :**

This can happen when you have sample data deployed and if you use git to retrieve your website to another environment.

The file `pub/media/styles.css` is excluded from your git repository by default (see line `/pub/media/*.*` of your .gitignore). This is why you can't see this file at all when pulling the repository.

When deploying static content, this file won't be generated as this is not a classic static file.

This file is **only** generated when deploying the sample data :

- `Magento_ThemeSampleData` module will add the content of the file `vendor/magento/module-cms-sample-data/fixtures/styles.css` to the file `pub/media/styles.css`
- `Magento_CmsSampleData` module will add the content of the file `vendor/magento/module-theme-sample-data/fixtures/styles.css` to the file `pub/media/styles.css`

*(see `Setup/Installer.php` file of each modules for more details).*

**Solution :**

For your tests using sample data, you can add the content of the `pub/media/styles.css` to your Design Configuration :

- Content > Design > Configuration
- Click on *Edit* on your theme
- HTML Head > Scripts and Style Sheets
- Remove the line including the `styles.css` file
- Add the content of what was in the file inside a `<style>` tag.

To know what was in the `pub/media/styles.css` (as it is missing now), check the fixture files mentioned in the first part, so you can retrieve the CSS code corresponding to your actual version.

*Note* : This method shouldn't be used in an actual production website, but as sample data are mainly used for testing and development purpose, this shouldn't be a problem you can get in production.

**Solution 2 :**

You could also add a line into your `.gitignore` file to add the file to your repository.

But again, such a specific case (using sample data) should not be added into a production website and its use should be restricted to your testing environments using sample data.

Here would be the line to add (after `/pub/media/*.*`) :

```
!/pub/media/styles.css
```

Comment: I was looking for why this has been added to the theme. Perfect answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Quick Solution

You can copy manually below css code and add it your theme.

[image]

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="{{MEDIA_URL}}styles.css" />
```

Also check your Magento folder and check for the styles.css file in the pub/media folder. If this file was present then give the pub folder the required rwx permission.

Than run CLI

```
php bin/magento c:f
```

Comment: MEDIA_URL is not getting replaced with actual url . styles.css is present