# Magento doesn't have CSS after installed?

Tags: magento2, css

**I have below page after install:**

[image]

I have referenced to this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/152446/after-installation-i-have-problems-with-magento-2) but it not solved my problem.

When I run *php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f*, I got this error: 
[image]

Comment: @fmsthird, Thank you, but different.

Comment: what do you mean by different? did it fix the issue?

Comment: I mean that I have fixed like that, but it not works

Comment: you have to run upgrade and redeploy static contents again

Answer (score 0):

**Run the following commands:**

```
 1. php bin/magento setup:upgrade
 2. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
 3. php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Then the website will be as the default.

Comment: Thanks@Teja, I've tried but the same. Do you think it's a problem with my PC?

Comment: Stil has the problem.

Comment: Could you please check my updated answer.

Comment: @MichaelTao, have you run php bin/magento setup:upgrade before deploying?

Comment: Yes, I just have performed and still get the error

Comment: Hi Teja, Do you know error: variable @mobile-cart-padding is undefined in file C:/xampp/htdocs/TaoDemo/magento2/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/source/_extends.less in _extends.less on line 927, column 35

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96788/discussion-between-teja-bhagavan-kollepara-and-michael-tao).